# show and hide table in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the IE6 browser. I want to show and hide `<table>` on certain conditions. I have tried to use the below code to show and hide the table

```
 document.getElementById("crCurrSlotTbl").style.display="table" //show the table
 document.getElementById("crCurrSlotTbl").style.display="none"; //hide the table
```

But it is working as fine in the IE8 but it is not working fine with IE6. I have tried various solutions such as wrapping it around the div tag than but neither of them work.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Nopes we are not using jquery we are using normal javascript

Comment: OMG! still supporting IE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

The `block` and `inline` values are supported explicitly as of Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.

```
document.getElementById("crCurrSlotTbl").style.display="block";
```

Ref:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try This
Step 1 : Declare class no-display. In this declare style display as none.
Step 2: When you need to show element

```
//remove class 

document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";
```

when you need to hide

```
//add class

document.getElementById("whatever").className = "no-display";
```

Comment: @Kshitiz: 
document.getElementById("whatever").className = "no-display"; Here whatever is id?

Comment: Is it right?     <OPTION class="market_code_dropdown" id="marketcod" VALUE=<%= strMktCode %>
 
 document.getElementById("marketcod").market_code_dropdown = "no-display";

Comment: you need to give is to select. 
Try it on simple text field first then you will understand easily.
Did you declared no-display class?

Comment: Couldn't understood bro :(

Answer (score -2):

use direct show hide.

```
document.getElementById("crCurrSlotTbl").show() //show the table
 document.getElementById("crCurrSlotTbl").hide(); //hide the table
```

Comment: show()  and hide() predefined function in javascript for show or hide.

Comment: can you provide any reference link

Comment: Visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_dialog_show_close see you get console error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` It seems that its function related to `dialog` element which is only supported in  `Chrome Canary` and `Safari 6.`