# Hide/Show is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having two dropdowns. Based on the first dropdown values, the second dropdown values are hidden. But hide() and show() is not working in IE 8. But working fine in Firefox.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function marketcd_dropdown_const(){
    alert($("#first").val());
    switch ($("#first").val())
    {

        case 'ONE':
            $('.market_code_dropdown').hide();  
            $('.instorder').hide();  
            $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        case 'TWO':
            $('.market_code_dropdown').hide();
            $('.instorder').hide();  
            $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        default:
            $('.market_code_dropdown').show();
            $('.instorder').show();  
            $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready function");
    $(document).bind('change', ".first_class", marketcd_dropdown_const);
    });
</script>
```

JSP:

```
<SELECT NAME=BillingSystem id="first" class="first_class" size="1" onchange="nuvoxcolumn(this);" >

                  <!-- // Option All  -->
                  <option value=<%= m_strALL %>

            <%
                if (m_bGet || m_strOldBillingSystem.equals("%"))
                    {%>
               <%= m_selected %>
            <%}
            %>
            >
         <%= m_strAllSearch %>
            <%Log.write("m_strAllSearch for billing system: "+m_strAllSearch); %>
         </option>


         <%
                while(m_strBillSystemList[iCount] != null)

                    {
                        String strBillSystem = m_strBillSystemList[iCount];
         %>
         <OPTION VALUE=<%= strBillSystem %>
         <%Log.write("m_strOldBillingSystem: "+m_strOldBillingSystem); %>
               <%
                        if (m_strOldBillingSystem != null)
                            {
                                if (m_strOldBillingSystem.equals(strBillSystem))
                                    {%>

                     <%= m_selected %>
                  <%}
                            }
                  %> >
            <%= strBillSystem %>
            <%Log.write("strBillSystem: "+strBillSystem); %>
            </option>
            <%
                        iCount++;
                    }
            %>

            </select>

<SELECT NAME=MarketCode id="second" size = 1>

           <!--   // Option All   -->




                  <option id="all_option" value=<%= m_strALL %>

               <%
                if (m_bGet || m_strOldMarketCode.equals("%"))
                    {%>
                  <%= m_selected %>
               <%}
               %> >
               <%= m_strAllSearch %>
               <%Log.write("m_strAllSearch for market code: "+m_strAllSearch); %>
               </option>

            <%
                while(m_strMktCodeList[iCount] != null)
                    {
                        String strMktCode = m_strMktCodeList[iCount];


            %>

            <OPTION class="market_code_dropdown" VALUE=<%= strMktCode %>
                 <%
                        if (m_strOldMarketCode != null)
                            {
                                if (m_strOldMarketCode.equals(strMktCode))
                                    {%>
                        <%= m_selected %>
                    <%}
                            }
                    %> >


               <%= strMktCode %> 
                  <%Log.write("strMktCode: "+strMktCode); %>



               </option>
               <%
                        iCount++;
                    }
               %> 
               </select>
```

Jquery version used:jQuery v1.4.2
Afterwords, i used latest jquery version.
Both are not working in IE 8.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: What's your JQuery version? versions 2.X do not support IE8.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: jQuery v1.4.2 and later i used latest jquery version. but it is not working for both

Comment: It can be related to IE8 compatibility mode I think. Instead a .hide() try : attr("style", "display: none;"). is it working ?

Comment: posted html code! please check it

Comment: Tried $('.market_code_dropdown').attr("style", "display: none;");  instead of $('.market_code_dropdown').hide(); but it is not working in IE 8

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488508/show-and-hide-table-in-ie6/23488636#23488636

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your code according to latest jQuery version ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready function");
    $(document).on('change', ".first_class", marketcd_dropdown_const);
    });
```

Or you can use jQuery migration plugin to support old version code

I run this code and it is working... just check it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function marketcd_dropdown_const(){
    alert($("#first").val());
    switch ($("#first").val())
    {

        case 'ONE':
            $('.market_code_dropdown').hide();  
           // $('.instorder').hide();  
           // $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        case 'TWO':
            $('.market_code_dropdown').hide();
        //    $('.instorder').hide();  
         //   $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        default:
            $('.market_code_dropdown').show();
         //   $('.instorder').show();  
        //    $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready function");
    $(document).bind('change', ".first_class", marketcd_dropdown_const);
    });
</script>
<body>
<SELECT NAME=BillingSystem id="first" class="first_class" size="1"   >

                  <!-- // Option All  -->
                  <option value=""  >Select</option>
                  <option value="ONE"  >test</option>



         <OPTION VALUE='TWO'>test1 </option>

            </select>

<SELECT NAME="MarketCode" id="second" size = "1" class="market_code_dropdown">

          <option value=""  >test</option>



         <OPTION VALUE='tt'>test1 </option>
               </select>
</body>
```

Use this javascript version...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function marketcd_dropdown_const(obj){

    switch (obj.value)
    {

        case 'ONE':
           document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
           // $('.instorder').hide();  
           // $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        case 'TWO':
            document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
        //    $('.instorder').hide();  
         //   $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';
         //   $('.instorder').show();  
        //    $('#all_option').prop('selected',true);
            break;

    }
}


</script>
<body>
<SELECT NAME=BillingSystem id="first" class="first_class" size="1" onChange=" marketcd_dropdown_const(this)"  >

                  <!-- // Option All  -->
                  <option value=""  >Select</option>
                  <option value="ONE"  >test</option>



         <OPTION VALUE='TWO'>test1 </option>

            </select>

<SELECT NAME="MarketCode"  id="second" size = "1" class="market_code_dropdown">

          <option value=""  >test</option>



         <OPTION VALUE='tt'>test1 </option>
               </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any way to work using jQuery v1.4.2 version?

Comment: Really sorry Agarwal. I am working in Development environment . Credentials are confidential. Can you please help me in any other options?

Comment: Problem is instead of this $('.market_code_dropdown').hide();   What can I use to hide the values in IE 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488508/show-and-hide-table-in-ie6/23488636  please see this. they have used javascript no display here.. Can I use it here?

Comment: instead of class selector use ID use this ..$('#market_code_dropdown').css('display','none');

Comment: How can I use jquery migration plugin to support old version code?

Comment: Nothing more.. just include migration plugin js file.. like jquery file

Comment: Can you please help me with javascript code instead of jquery to hide the values. You are my only hope. Please help me bro!

Comment: I modified the code with only javascript..just check it

Comment: Is it helpful or not?

Comment: Script is not called the function :( function marketcd_dropdown_const(obj)

Comment: I am calling it on select tag onChange event

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery version isn't up to date and this is the main problem in my opinion.

There's probably a workaround to solve the issue, but honestly, trying to make older versions work is just an ongoing headache.

Here is my solution that will work for you

Create a new class in your css:

```
.hideme { display: none; }
```

Now, instead of

```
$('.market_code_dropdown').hide();
$('.market_code_dropdown').show();
```

use

```
$('.market_code_dropdown').addClass('hideme');
$('.market_code_dropdown').removeClass('hideme');
```

There functions are supported since v.1.4

Comment: Got it. IE8 doesn't support the query by class name, so give your element a unique id and use it instead of the class name. In fact you'd better do that throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: Could you help me with javascript?

Comment: Simply go to every element and give it some id, for this example let's call it `market_dropdown`. and now your selector will work by using `$('#market_dropdown')`. Don't forget to do the same in your `$(document).ready()` function where you also select an element by class name.

Comment: I tried something like this...but it is not working...could u please take a look...http://jsfiddle.net/4j5Lb/1/

Comment: First, set the script loading to one of the `no wrap` options instead of 'onLoad' to make the code run. Second, it appears IE don't like hiding `option` elements. Try using `.disabled = false` instead of `.style.display = 'block'` and `.disabled = true` instead of `.style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: if i use disabled, the respected value is disabled and i cant able to select it. but i need to hide that value

Comment: Bad news, with IE8 and JQuery 1.4.2 you are running fast out of options. Looks like the best way is for you to dynamically build the droplist according to selection, and this is a whole other level.